# Guake Terminal transparency sometimes acts weird

Tags: 11.10, unity

I am using Guake since 11.04, and I like it very much, it's my default terminal. Obviously I am using it's transparency option.

Because I haven't paying too much attention to it, I am not sure if the default transparency should be. Should it make all the background window transparent and show me the desktop behind? Or should it be transparent only to the first application It has open in the background.

I ask this question because I have noticed in the past week both situation happen on my Ubuntu 11.10 install. So right now I am puzzled about how it should be. And because it shouldn't behave different from day to day, I am suspecting Guake not be fully compatible with Unity.

Any Ideas?

I attach a picture of how I have it now, transparent to the desktop through Chrome and Nautilus[image: quake transparency to desktop]

Edit:
I have just looked at Guake homepage on this [screenshot.](http://guake.org/screenshots/1)

I can clearly see that the transparency should not go until the desktop, but it should show the first application it has in the background.

Edit2:
Killed Guake and restarted it. The transparency works ok now:
[image]

Comment: It seems it is not using real transparency as is done in a composited environment. So it uses pseudo-transparency where it copies the wallpaper and uses that as background to give the illusion of transparency.

Comment: I use `stjerm` it is great and supports true transparency.

Comment: As you can see in my second picture, the transparency works great, so it must be some incompatibility with Unity. Or the fact that at start up it should wait for compiz to fully load up? This may be the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, this issue occurs with other terminals with transparency too (like Terminator) if they are set to start when you log in. If however, you manually start them (that's why it worked after you killed Guake), this issue doesn't occur.

So to fix it, you can create a simple script to launch Guake with a delay. Create a file called "guake-start.sh" in your home folder and paste this:

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 15 && guake
```

"sleep 15" will make Guake start with a 15 seconds delay. If 15 isn't working for you, try a different value. Then save the file and make it executable using the following command:

```
chmod +x ~/guake-start.sh
```

And add guake-start.sh to your startup applications instead of the regular Guake executable.

Comment: I am already using this trick with sleep 15 or 30 for several other application that need to start up later. One of them is conky. On another topic, I thank you for a previous answer of yours, in which you provided a way to customize the width of the Guake terminal. P.S: Salutare de la un co-national.

Answer (score 0):

Just type this in terminal

```
sudo nano /usr/bin/guake
```

and put

```
sleep 10 exec -a guake $PYTHON -OO $GUAKEPATH/guake.py "$@"
```